# Intercepting Android Menu button in a PopupWindow

Tags: android, android-view, android-menu, android-keypad

I have a main activity that does not use option menu. I need to implement this behavior:
1. When the Android Menu button is pressed, a popup is shown
2. When the Android Menu button is pressed again, the popup is dismissed.

I know how to do #1 by overriding onKeyDown() in the main activity but don't know how to do #2. When the popup is shown, the onKeyDown() of the main activity is not triggered anymore.

How do I capture the Android Menu button when the main activity has an open popup?  (in my case, the popup is a PopupWindow with an inflated view).

BTW, I tried to set a key listener on the main view of the popup but it is not triggered

```
    mTopView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {           
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            LogUtil.debug("*** Key: %d", keyCode);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: If it were me, I would make the "pop-up" into its own activity, that way it can be done the exact same way as in the MainActivity. Just call finish() when menu is pressed in the pop-up activity.

Comment: Thanks. I have a lot of code invested in the popup solution (it needs to popup at a specific location and shape in relation to an anchor view). If I will not find a way to make it to work I will try to activity approach.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Answering my own question. Calling setFocusableInTouchMode() on the PopupWindow view does the trick and causes the listener to work.

```
PopupMenu popupMenu = ...
...
popupWindow.getContentView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
popupMenu.getContentView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {        
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode ==  KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && 
                event.getRepeatCount() == 0 && 
                event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            // ... payload action here. e.g. popupMenu.dismiss();
            return true;
        }                
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        // Do Stuff
    }
```